# Sharing/passing data between two components

Tags: angular

I have two components(each defined for a route). Inside one component(say component A), i have written a click event that makes a http call and provides a json. Here is my click event:

```
@Output() emitData = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private appService: AppService){
}

// click event 
getData() {    
  this.appService.getData();    
  this.emitData.emit(this.appService.getData());    
}
```

On the other component, i have written the following:

```
emitData(data: any){
   console.log("Data:",data);
}
```

Well i have seen the @Input() and @Output(), but here the @Output() is not providing me the expected output.(I think the reason could be that both components are at the same level).

Could someone please help me for the same.

Comment: Use a shared service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 0):

You have to emit the data only from `getData` function as below :

```
getData() {    
  this.appService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
    this.emitData.emit(res);    
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else i have to write(in the http service), as its showing .subscribe is not a function

Comment: i am able to resolve the subscribe error. still not able to pass the data though